# Create unique ID based on repeated IDs

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I received some data from a colleague who is working with animal observations recorded in several transects. However my colleague used the same three ID codes for identifying each transect: 1, 7, 13 and 19. I would like to replace the repeated IDs with unique IDs. This image shows what I want to do:

[image]

Here's the corresponding code:

```
example_data<-structure(list(ID_Transect = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 
                                             7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
                                             19L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), 
                             transect_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                   2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                   5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                             -36L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data.table` `rleid` -

```
example_data$transect_id <- data.table::rleid(example_data$ID_Transect)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

---

In base R we can use `rle` -

```
with(rle(example_data$ID_Transect), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
```

Or `diff` + `cumsum` -

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(example_data$ID_Transect) != 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(example_data)[, transect_id := rleid(ID_Transect)]
```